# How to use ContainerList in lwuit 1.5?

Tags: list, java-me, lwuit

My list having variable length list items. ContainerList supports variable length list items. When I explored it on internet, I can't find any samples for ContainerList. Give me a sample piece of code to work on ContainerList.

Comment: Use a List, it will work for what you want to do

Comment: List won't support variable length list items.

Comment: sure? wgat do you want to mean witj "variable lenght"?

Comment: I am having one list item as container. One list item container having 5 components, second list item having 3 components and the third list item having 4 components. When I see the output, there is a long space between second and third list item because list takes the maximum size list item as the default size for all list items. To avoid that, I need to use ContainerList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWUIT demo contains a ContainerList sample in the Scroll demo.

There is also an explanation in our blog http://codenameone.blogspot.com/

Generally ContainerList is a drop-in replacement for list, just replace the usage of List with ContainerList and it should work pretty seamlessly (albeit slower).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Vector variableLengthVector = new Vector();

variableLengthVector.clear();

for(int i=0;i< variableLengthStringArray.length;i++)
{
variableLengthVector.add(variableLengthStringArray[i]); 
}

List myListToBeDisplaye = new List(variableLengthVector);
```

**variableLengthStringArray-->** It contains the items that you wish to show in your list.

So whenever you want to display a list , just populate a vector and initialize your list with that vector. Ensure, that you clear that vector or re initialize the vector before populating it.

Now, simply paste your list on a form or wherever you wish to display it..

Ok, you can find stuff about containerList here:

http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/list/ContainerList.html

You can use a container list like this:

ContainerList abc = new ContainerList(new DefaultListModel(variableLengthVector));

Comment: No Nikhil. My single list item having 5 components like 2 Labels, 1 TextArea and 2 Images. How can I use Vector in this situation.